# Validação de strings utilizando while em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, condição

O seguinte código tem a intenção de pedir o sexo do usuário ("f" ou "m") e caso o usuário digite outra letra, ele continuaria pedindo para digitar "f" ou "m", todavia ao executá-lo ele continua pedindo o sexo, mesmo usuário digitando "f" ou "m".

```
sexo = 'o'

while (sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm'):
    sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
```

Acontece a mesma coisa quando solicito o o estado civil do usuário :

```
estado_civil = 'a'
while estado_civil != 's' or estado_civil != 'c' or estado_civil != 'v' or estado_civil != 'd':
    estado_civil = input('Digite seu estado civil (s, c, v, d): ')
```

---

Eu consegui resolver o problema utilizando o código a seguir, mas gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual não funciona utilizando o código acima:

```
while True:
  sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
  if sexo == 'f' or sexo == 'm':
    break

while True:
  estado_civil = input('Digite seu estado civil (s, c, v, d): ')
  if estado_civil == 's' or estado_civil == 'c' or estado_civil == 'v' or estado_civil == 'd':
    break
```

Comment: Mude de `while (sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm'):` para `while (sexo != 'f' and sexo != 'm'):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O motivo pelo qual um código funcionou, mas o outro não, é muito simples.

No `while`, a condição serve para indicar se ele vai continuar executando ou não. Enquanto a condição for verdadeira, ele continua.

Então você fez:

```
while (sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm'):
    sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
```

A condição do `while` é `sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm'`, que na verdade são duas condições mais o [operador `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). No fim, toda essa expressão verifica se `sexo` é diferente de "f" **ou** se é diferente de "m". O resultado do `or` é verdadeiro (`True`) se qualquer uma das duas condições for verdadeira (só uma delas já serve). Ou seja, se `sexo` for diferente de "f", o resultado é `True`. Mas se for diferente de "m", também é `True`.

Então o que acontece se você digita "f"? Ele não será diferente de "f", mas será diferente de "m". Como o `or` só precisa que uma das condições seja verdade, o resultado é `True`, e por isso o `while` continua executando.

E se você digita "m"? Ele será diferente de "f", o que já é suficiente para que o resultado do `or` seja `True`, e por isso o `while` continua executando.

Aliás, essa condição sempre será verdadeira: **qualquer valor** diferente de "f" cairá na primeira condição e o resultado será `True`. E se digitar "f", a primeira condiçao é falsa, mas a segunda ("f" é diferente de "m") é verdadeira, também resultando em `True`. Portanto, você criou um *loop* infinito.

| Valor | `sexo != 'f'` | `sexo != 'm'` | `sexo != 'f' or sexo != 'm'` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "f" | `False` | `True` | `True` |
| "m" | `True` | `False`***** | `True` |
| não é "f" nem "m" | `True` | `True`***** | `True` |

Ou seja, a condição sempre será `True`, independente do valor de `sexo`. Por isso que o `while` continua executando, independente do que for digitado.

<sup>***** Na verdade, se a primeira expressão for `True`, a segunda nem sequer é avaliada, já que os operadores *booleanos* são *short circuit* (só avaliam o mínimo necessário: como no `or` basta que uma delas seja `True`, se a primeira for, a segunda nem é avaliada).</sup>

---

Sendo assim, o que você quer é que o *loop* continue executando somente se o `sexo` não for "f" e nem "m" (ou seja, se digitar algo que não é "f" **e** também não é "m", eu continuo, mas se for um dos dois, eu paro). Por isso o operador correto a ser utilizado é o `and`:

```
sexo = ''
while sexo != 'f' and sexo != 'm': # repare que não precisa dos parênteses
    sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
```

O `and` só resulta em `True` se ambas as condições forem verdadeiras. Ou seja, se eu digitar "f", a primeira condição é falsa (não é diferente de "f") e o resultado será `False`. E se digitar "m", a primeira condição é verdadeira (é diferente de "f"), mas a segunda é falsa (não é diferente de "m"), e o resultado também será `False`. Portanto, se eu digitar "f" ou "m", ele sai do `while`. Para qualquer outro valor, o *loop* continua.

Veja a diferença:

| Valor | `sexo != 'f'` | `sexo != 'm'` | `sexo != 'f' and sexo != 'm'` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "f" | `False` | `True` | `False` |
| "m" | `True` | `False` | `False` |
| não é "f" nem "m" | `True` | `True` | `True` |

Ou seja, agora a condição só é verdadeira se eu não digitar "f" nem "m", e aí o `while` continua. Se eu digitar qualquer um deles, o resultado é `False` e o `while` é interrompido.

---

Eu particularmente não gosto dessa solução de dar um valor arbitrário para a variável antes do *loop*, só para que ele entre lá uma vez. Prefiro fazer como o seu segundo código:

```
while True:
  sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
  if sexo == 'f' or sexo == 'm':
    break
```

Ele funciona porque em vez de `!=` (diferente), você usou `==` (igual), então agora a condição verifica se foi digitado "f" ou "m" (se `sexo` é igual a "f" **ou** igual a "m"). Se eu digitar "f" ou "m", ele entra no `if` e o `break` interrompe o `while`. Para qualquer outro valor, ele não entra no `if` e o *loop* continua.

Então agora ficou assim:

| Valor | `sexo == 'f'` | `sexo == 'm'` | `sexo == 'f' or sexo == 'm'` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "f" | `True` | `False` | `True` |
| "m" | `False` | `True` | `True` |
| não é "f" nem "m" | `False` | `False` | `False` |

Ou seja, se digitar "f" ou "m", entra no `if` e interrompe o *loop*. Se digitar qualquer outra coisa que não seja "f" nem "m", não entra no `if` e o `while` continua executando.

Por isso que o segundo código funcionou, mas o primeiro não.

---

Claro, você pode implementar de outras maneiras, como as outras respostas sugerem (`if sexo in ('m', 'f')`, etc), mas aí já não é o foco da pergunta. O importante é entender como as condicionais funcionam e aplicá-las corretamente.

Resumindo:

- uma expressão com `or` resulta em `True` se **qualquer uma** das condições for verdadeira
- uma expressão com `and` resulta em `True` se **todas** as condições forem verdadeiras

Comment: Uma aula, obrigado! :)

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando **python 3.8** ou superior, pode implementar **[Assigment Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)** (Expressão de atribuição) no seu código para realizar as verificações. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
while (s := input('Sexo: [M/F] ').upper()) not in {'M', 'F'}:
    print('Sexo INVÁALIDO!')

while (e := input('Estado Civil: [S/C/V/D] ').upper()) not in {'S', 'C', 'V', 'D'}:
    print('Estado Civil INVÁLIDO!')
```

**Como funciona o código?**

O primeiro bloco **while** verifica se o valor atribuído à variável **s** pertence ou não ao conjunto...

```
{'M', 'F'}
```

Enquanto não pertencer, será exibido a mensagem de erro e, também, será novamente solicitado o sexo. Caso contrário, o loop será encerrado e passará para o próximo bloco de códigos.

O segundo bloco while tem funcionamento análogo ao do primeiro. Só que desta vez a verificação terá quatro possibilidades que são:

```
{'S', 'C', 'V', 'D'}
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá, podemos resolver esse problema evitando o uso do ***break***.

```py
sexo = ''
while sexo not in ['f','m']:
  sexo = input('Digite seu sexo (m / f): ')
  sexo = sexo.lower()
  
estadoCivil = ''
while estadoCivil not in ['s','c','v','d']:
  estadoCivil = input('Digite seu estado civil (s, c, v, d): ')
  estadoCivil = estadoCivil.lower()
```